# kivymd MDbottomnavigation on_tab_press

Tags: python, kivymd

This is my first time trying out KivyMD. I have the following kivymd bottomnavigation tabs.
I'm trying to get the name of the tab that is pressed such that I want to display a datatable etc in one of the tab, some profile functionality in another tab etc.
However, when I'm trying to use the `on_tab_press` event in the `MDBottomNavigation`, it works. However, it gives me an object instead of the actual value (the tab name that is pressed).
In the below `main.py`, the `on_tab_press` function gives me the following. How do I get the name from the `on_tab_press` event?

```
print(type(args[0])) - <class 'kivymd.uix.bottomnavigation.MDBottomNavigationItem'>
print(*args) - <MDTab name='screen1', text='tab1'>
```

main.py

```
from kivymd.theming import ThemeManager

class MainApp(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        theme_cls = ThemeManager()
        self.root = Builder.load_file("main.kv")
        return self.root

    def on_tab_press(self, *args):
        print(type(args[0]))
        print(*args)
        # returns 
        # <class 'kivymd.uix.bottomnavigation.MDBottomNavigationItem'>
        # <MDTab name='screen1', text='tab1'>
```

main.kv

```
<BottomNav>:
    #name: 'hello'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation:'vertical'
        MDToolbar:
            title: 'folio'
            md_bg_color: .2, .2, .2, 1
            specific_text_color: 1, 1, 1, 1
        MDBottomNavigation:
            panel_color: 1,1,1,1
            MDBottomNavigationItem:
                name: 'screen1'
                text: 'tab1'
                #icon: 'language-python'
                on_tab_press: app.on_tab_press(*args)
                #on_tab_press: app.current = 'home_screen'
                #MDLabel:
                #    text: 'tab1'
                #    halign: 'center'
            MDBottomNavigationItem:
                name: 'screen2'
                text: 'tab2'
                on_tab_press: app.on_tab_press(*args)
                #icon: 'language-cpp'
                #MDLabel:
                #    text: 'I programming of C++'
                #    halign: 'center'
            MDBottomNavigationItem:
                name: 'screen3'
                text: 'tab3'
                on_tab_press: app.on_tab_press(*args)
                #icon: 'language-javascript'
                MDLabel:
                    text: 'JS'
                    halign: 'center'
```

Answer (score 0):

#### The Problem

You are using `*args` as an argument in your `def on_tab_press` method. As far as I know `*` unpacks the data passedand returns a tuple, here data is **args** which is your  `BottomNavigationItem`.

However you are passing an object `kivymd.uix.bottomnavigation.MDBottomNavigationItem` and trying to treat it like an iterable by using `print(*args)` which is causing a bit of trouble

#### Solution

Change your method to something like this `def on_press_method(self, args)` and access the **name** and **text** of the object using `print(args.name)` and `print(args.text)`

#### Example Code

```
from kivy.lang import Builder

from kivymd.uix.screen import Screen
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.theming import ThemeManager
from kivymd.uix.button import MDRectangleFlatButton

Builder.load_string("""
<MainScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation:'vertical'
        MDToolbar:
            title: 'folio'
            md_bg_color: .2, .2, .2, 1
            specific_text_color: 1, 1, 1, 1
        MDBottomNavigation:
            panel_color: 1,1,1,1
            MDBottomNavigationItem:
                name: 'screen1'
                text: 'tab1'
                icon: 'language-python'
                on_tab_press: app.on_tab_press(*args)
                #on_tab_press: app.current = 'home_screen'
                #MDLabel:
                #    text: 'tab1'
                #    halign: 'center'
            MDBottomNavigationItem:
                name: 'screen2'
                text: 'tab2'
                on_tab_press: app.on_tab_press(*args)
                #icon: 'language-cpp'
                #MDLabel:
                #    text: 'I programming of C++'
                #    halign: 'center'
            MDBottomNavigationItem:
                name: 'screen3'
                text: 'tab3'
                on_tab_press: app.on_tab_press(*args)
                #icon: 'language-javascript'
                MDLabel:
                    text: 'JS'
                    halign: 'center'

""")

class MainScreen(Screen):
    pass

class MainApp(MDApp):
    def on_tab_press(self, args):
        
        print(type(args))
        print(args.name)
        print(args.text)


    def build(self):
        return MainScreen()
MainApp().run()
```